# How to configure PurgeCSS for vue-cli-3 projects with TailwindCSS? (including responsive classes)

Tags: vue-cli-3, tailwind-css, css-purge

I'm trying to deploy a vue-cli-3 project. I used TailwindCSS and created a `vue.config.js` file and it's working, but responsive classes are not being included. I searched about a regex, using a extractor in a webpack.config.js file but it didn't work. What should I do to have this working?

Here's my `vue.config.js` file

```
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin')
const glob = require('glob-all')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // Merged into the final Webpack config
    plugins: [
      new PurgecssPlugin({
        paths: glob.sync([
          path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
          path.join(__dirname, './**/*.vue'),
          path.join(__dirname, './src/**/*.js')
        ])
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Where should I put the extractor array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your configurations as following:

```
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin')
const glob = require('glob-all')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // Merged into the final Webpack config
    plugins: [
      new PurgecssPlugin({
        paths: glob.sync([
          path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
          path.join(__dirname, './src/**/*.vue'),
          path.join(__dirname, './src/**/*.js')
        ]),
        extractors: [
          {
            extractor: class TailwindExtractor {
              static extract(content) {
                return content.match(/[A-z0-9-_:\/]+/g) || [];
              }
            },
            extensions: ['html', 'vue', 'js'],
          },
        ],
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, I've noted that you used `'./**/*.vue'` is that was intentionally or by mistake?